# Ошибка "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch."

Tags: excel, visual-basic

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники форума! Подскажите, пожалуйста, начинающему программисту, почему выдается ошибка при запуске следующего программного кода

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
Dim MNO() As Single 'массив начальных отметок деформационных марок
Dim MKO() As Single 'массив конечных отметок деформационных марок
Dim kdm As Integer 'количество деформационных марок
Dim n As Integer 'размер массива деформационных марок
kdm = InputBox("Введите количество деформационных марок", "Вычисление промежуточных отметок осадочных марок")
Debug.Print "kdm = ", kdm
n = kdm
ReDim MNO(1 To n) As Single: ReDim MKO(1 To n) As Single
Dim i As Integer 'счетчик цикла
For i = 1 To n
Debug.Print "i=", i
MNO(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
MKO(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
'Debug.Print MNO(i)
'Debug.Print MKO(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Значения для массивов MNO и MKO расположены на листе 1 в 2-х столбцах А1:А32, В1:В32. Выдается ошибка Run-time error '13' Type mismatch.
Искренне буду признателен вам за вашу профессиональную помощь. Всем вам желаю удачи и успехов!!!

Answer (score 1):

У меня отработало без проблем.

Можно упростить.

*Option Base 1* не обязательно, Вы явно задаете размерность (*ReDim*).

Указывать тип данных второй раз, при задании размерности - лишнее.

*n = kdm* - достаточно одной переменной.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
Dim MNO() As Single 'массив начальных отметок деформационных марок
Dim MKO() As Single 'массив конечных отметок деформационных марок
Dim kdm As Long 'количество деформационных марок
Dim i As Long ' счетчик цикла
    kdm = InputBox("Введите количество деформационных марок", "Вычисление промежуточных отметок осадочных марок")
    ReDim MNO(1 To kdm)
    ReDim MKO(1 To kdm)

    For i = 1 To kdm
        MNO(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        MKO(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Формируются два массива *MNO* и *MKO*.